# Push failed, heroku, django, scrapy-heroku

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

Tried to add  scrapy-heroku and dependencies to requirements.txt before pushing to heroku.

```
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-IY3d_3/distribute/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
remote:                setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
remote:                dist.run_commands()
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
remote:                self.run_command(cmd)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
remote:                cmd_obj.run()
remote:              File "setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
remote:                writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
remote:              File "pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
remote:                if require: self.require(env, installer)
remote:              File "pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
remote:                working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
remote:              File "pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
remote:                dm = self._dep_map
remote:              File "pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
remote:                self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
remote:              File "pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
remote:                from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
remote:            ImportError: No module named _markerlib
```

I solved this problem in local after I installed a new env with --distribute, but the error persists on heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems began when I tried to add scrapy-heroku package to heroku. One of my  dependencies contains the  distribute package. Just put the scrapy-heroku package on the beginning of requirements.txt file.